# Three Partition-Function Algorithms Comparison

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, time-complexity

I have implemented three algorithms codes, in Swift:

1- Polynomial coefficient:

```
 // create polynomial
func arrangePoly(ofTerms term: Int, toLength len: Int) -> [Int] {
    var a = Array(repeating: 0, count: len+1)

    for i in stride(from: 0, to: a.count, by: term) {
        a[i] = 1
    }
    return a
}
// polynomial product
func productToN(array1 a: [Int], arrayb b: [Int], toPower n: Int) -> [Int] {
    var res = Array(repeating: 0, count: n+1)

    for (pa, ca) in a.enumerated() {
        for (pb, cb) in b.enumerated() {
            if pa+pb <= n {
                res[pa+pb] += ca*cb
            }
        }
    }
    return res
}
// test code: partition of N
var p1 = arrangePoly(ofTerms: 1, toLength: N)
var res = p1

for i in 2...N {
    res = productToN(array1: res, arrayb: arrangePoly(ofTerms: i, toLength: N), toPower: N)
}
print(res[N])   // coefficient of x^N
```

2- Euler recurrence relations:

```
func eulerPartition(_ n: Int) -> Int {
    if n < 0 {
        return 0
    } else if n == 0 {
        return 1
    } else {
        var k = 1
        var sum = 0
        while k <= n {
            let sign = power(-1, k-1)
            sum += sign * (eulerPartition(n-(k*((3*k)-1)/2)) + eulerPartition(n-(k*((3*k)+1)/2)))
            k += 1
        }
        return sum
    }
}
```

3- Divisor sum formula:

```
// sigma(k) is the well-known sum of divisors of k
func part(_ n: Int) -> Int {
    if n < 0 {
        return 0
    } else if n == 0 {
        return 1
    } else {
        var k = 1
        var sum = 0
        while k <= n {
            sum += sigma(k) * part(n-k)
            k += 1
        }
        return sum / n
    }
}
```

All the three versions gives the same results for each n >= 1, but with different efficiency. While the Euler recurrence algorithm is assumed, [theoretically](http://knowledge.e.southern.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1038&context=senior_research), to be the fastest of the three, the polynomial coefficient algorithm works the best on my core2duo  laptop in spite of it is not recursively coded like the others. I am sure I have done something wrong, but I can not figure what or where.

Any idea?

Comment: Questions about particular programming languages are off-topic here, but questions about algorithms (described in pseudocode) are on-topic.

Comment: Have you tried to estimate the running time of the algorithms?

Comment: For n = 35, for example, running time for Euler method is ~41 sec, while it takes less than 0.1 sec in the poly-coeff. method.

Comment: I meant the asymptotic running time of the underlying algorithms.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus No. How to do it?

Comment: This is a rather broad question. We have [a post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) on the subject.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Actually, most of my information on these methods comes from this [paper](http://knowledge.e.southern.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1038&context=senior_research) on the internet.

Comment: The paper already includes complexity analyses of the various algorithms. That is, for each of the algorithms there is an analysis of its asymptotic running time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of the Euler method doesn't use memoization, so you keep computing and recomputing the same values. This is like computing the Fibonacci numbers along the following lines:

```
Fibonacci(n)
  if n = 0 or n = 1, return n
  otherwise, return Fibonacci(n-1) + Fibonacci(n-2)
```

You should modify the implementation so that after calculating `eulerPartition` for a certain $n$, if you are given the same $n$ again then you immediately return the previously calculated value.